# Spring Oauth Get Current User

Tags: java, spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I'm developing a system with 3 smaller projects, which are as follows:

- a client
- a ressource server
- a authentication server

The authentication server has a register and a login page. The resource server is secured by the authentication server.

From the client I want to access the resource via REST API. The client is calling the resource server via `OAuth2RestTemplate` from Spring to access the resource. I managed to access the resource, after I authenticated myself.

Now to the problem. At the client I need to know the current user to display the the username and enabling the user to change his profile.

I tried to access the principal of the user via spring security with

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

but it just returned `null`.
So my question is: Is there a way to get the current logged in user with the `OAuth2RestTemplate`?

Edit:

So I decided to change the plan to implement a link in my authentication server, which returns the user information. The problem is, when I want to talk the authentication server via `OAuth2RestTemplate`the authentication server just returns the login page. Everything works fine, when I call the page from browser or when I want to talk to the resource server via `OAuth2RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a TokenEnhancer to your AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer in Authorization server. You can add User information to the token as additional info map.

Here is a sample implementation of a custom TokenEnhancer,

```
    public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {

        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        UserDetails user = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

        additionalInfo.put("<custom_user_info>", user.getUsername());

        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);

        return accessToken;
    }

}
```

In your Authorization server,

```
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenEnhancer(new CustomTokenEnhancer());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that, but after I added the `CustomTokenEnhancer`, I get an `AccessTokenRequiredException: OAuth2 access denied` on the client side. I guess it has to do with the auto-config on the authentication server side. Guess I have to dive more in the configuration on the authentication server side.

Comment: Show the exception, it must be in your Authorization server

Answer (score 0):

Add authentication object to security context holder after successfull authentication, by overriding method of class AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

```
    public void successfulAuthentication(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
             FilterChain chain, 
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException

                 {
             // Add the authentication to the Security context 
   SecurityContextHolder
.getContext()
.setAuthentication(authentication); 

            }
```